# Как выстроить структуру БД

Tags: база-данных, структуры-данных

Добрый день, есть задача разработать БД таким образом, чтобы можно было определить расстояние между двумя станциями. Но проблема в том, что все тарифное расстояние РЖД находится на бумаге так сказать, либо в электронном виде, вот пример(http://lawrussia.ru/2001_legislation_of_russia_documents/russian_laws_1547.htm). В принципе, я немного имею идею, как сделать алгоритм расчета от станции А до станции Б, ноя  не могу никак придумать, как лучше организовать структуру БД. Есть Страна, Есть дорога, есть участок, на это участке набор остановочных пунктов, вот как можно лучше всего сделать это, ведь не буду я для каждого узла делать отдельные таблицы, может кто понимает в этом, подскажите плиз. Пока идея, все станции запихнуть в одну таблицу, и сделать ссылки на узлы, узлы на дороги, а дороги на страны, но это как-то не очень получается.

Я в этом не особо силен, поэтому мог некорректно вопрос составить.

Comment: Я думаю вам нужно создать базу в соответствии с данной таблицей, и добавить еще колонку узла. Таким образом получится та же таблица где выборку можно сделать по по id узла. Да и сами станции тоже вынесите в отдельную таблицу. Т.е. в итоге три таблицы: станции, узлы и расстояния.

Comment: вот я это вроде и понимаю, и даже нарисовал, а как это в БД выглядит никак не могу понять. Т.е. у меня есть таблица со станциями из кодами уже, вот как будет выглядит таблица расстояний? меня тут больше всего в тупик вогнало

Comment: Но я принял ответ, как вариант, который можно проработать, всегда его можно изменить :) СУБД будет MySQL

Comment: Вот как раз в MySQL с деревьями лучше не работать. В принципе я бы конечно просто выбрал PostgreSQL и не парился. С другой стороны нужны ли тут деревья в принципе ... Мне вот интересно, по той ссылке что вы дали есть станции между двумя узлами, как я понял, только вот суммы расстояний до одного и другого узла не всегда одинакова, там +-1 км бывает. т.е. выходит, по той таблице, что расстояние туда-обратно не совпадает ... этот нюанс должен быть отражен в БД ?

Comment: бывают узлы, принадлежащие 2м и более дорогам ? Если да, то каково максимально возможное кол-во дорог, примыкающих к узлу, больше 2х же возможно ?

Comment: На самом деле нет, расстояние от А до Б через одинаковые узлы и обратно одинаковы, тут не сильно играет роль +/- 20 км даже. Станций без узлов нет, то есть один узел переходит в другой, у станции может быть два и более узлов, она может быть началом одного и концом другого

Comment: Не, узлы принадлежащие двум и более дорогам нет, не видел.

Comment: То есть задача, рассчитать кротчайшее расстояние между А и Б. Но для этого сначала надо все это безобразие в БД грамотно перенести, с чем у меня как раз и тупик

Comment: вообще странно, ведь способы сообщения между дорогами должны существовать, а значит должны существовать и станции, где эти дороги сходятся. вот идет наша Киевская жд, упирается где то в укржалiзнiцу, значит должна быть станция (или узел) где не просто две дороги сошлись, а сошлись две дороги из разных стран

Comment: И кстати, я так понимаю, узел это просто почти обычная станция, только она собственно назначена узловой ? Т.е. фактически у нас есть просто сеть станций, у которых определен их тип. пока типов 2: обычная и узел, так ?

Comment: По поводу границы да, нет соединения, то есть на границе РФ и Украины связь потеряется, но в этом руководстве пишут, что в таких случаях еще учитывать надо расстояние до госграницы.  Вот кстати более наглядно https://tr4.info/railway/. Узел ,это набор станций, от узловой-А до узловой-Б

Comment: Есть сервисы, где расстояния рассчитываются, но нет нигде готового решения, поэтому мне пришлось это делать самому. Есть сайт с открытым OAPI и если через Fidller глянуть, то он делает тупо запрос в БД (http://poisk-vagonov.ru)

Comment: Вернемся к первой ссылке, вот 3я строка там в таблице, станция "Леджет", она к какому узлу принадлежит (вы только что сказали что узел включает много станций)

Comment: К узлу ЯЛАМА (ЭКСП.)  - БАЛАДЖАРЫ. Он в себя включает станции от Ялама до Баладжары . если смотреть таблицу , это строки от 1 до 24. От Ялама до Леджета 13 км

Comment: Я немного дезинформировал, назвав узлом, не узел, а участок, только что до меня это дошло (( Участок  ЯЛАМА (ЭКСП.) - БАЛАДЖАРЫ, на нем узловые станции ЯЛАМА (ЭКСП.) и БАЛАДЖАРЫ, на этом участке есть набор станций

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69096/discussion-between--and-mike).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для ответа на этот вопрос необходимо вспомнить немого теории.

Для поиска Вам идеально подходит структура данных - [матрица растояний](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0_%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9). Фактически, это квадартная матрица, в которой по осях находятся идексы станций, а значения по этому индексу и есть искомое растояние. Это именно та структура к которой нужно стремится при работе в программном коде. Но у неё есть небостатки. Она обладает высокой избыточностью. Фактически вы дублируете растояние из узла А в узел Б и наоборот т.е. Вам это придётся дублировать. Кроме того, добавление новых станций будет требовать изменения структуры БД, для расширения на добавляемые станции.

Если посмотреть внимательно - то в этой задаче данные о растояниях будут сильно "прорежены". Т.к. почти у всех станций растояний м.б. только два - к предыдущей и последующей станции. И только у узлов их будет больше. Наиболее подходящим в этом случае будет хранить информацию о растояних отдельно от станций.

```
CREATE TABLE STATION (
    STATION_ID INT PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE STATION_DISTANCE (
     STATION1_ID INT,
     STATION2_ID INT,
     DISTANCE NUMERIC NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (STATION1_ID, DISTANCE, STATION2_ID),
     FOREIGN KEY (STATION1_ID) REFERENCES STATION (STATION_ID),
     FOREIGN KEY (STATION2_ID) REFERENCES STATION (STATION_ID)
 );
```

Такая структура БД предоставит достаточно удобное хранение записи о растоянии, но совершить поиск оптимального пути на уровне базы данных при указанных условиях, не предоставляется возможным.

Поиск в этом случае можно будет совершить двумя способами:

1. Способ с предварительной подготовкой и подниманием всей информации о путях из БД.
2. Способ требующий уточняющих запросов.

Первый - потребует подготовки которая заключается в постороении из этой таблицы матрицы растояний к примеру при помощи алгоритма [Флойда - Уоршелла](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%A4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%B4%D0%B0_%E2%80%94_%D0%A3%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B0). И хотя этот алгоритм достаточно тяжёлый его результат, можно сохранить сериализовав матрицу растояний в файл и далее работать с ним, при этом его модификацию потребуется выполнять только при изменении структуры ЖД, что не так и часто.

При таком подходе можно быстро находить нужное растояние по матрице растояний.

Второй - базируется на [алгоритме Дейкстры для разреженных графов](https://acm.khpnets.info/w/index.php?title=%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%8B#.D0.A0.D0.B5.D0.B0.D0.BB.D0.B8.D0.B7.D0.B0.D1.86.D0.B8.D1.8F_.D0.B4.D0.BB.D1.8F_.D1.80.D0.B0.D0.B7.D1.80.D0.B5.D0.B6.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.BD.D1.8B.D1.85_.D0.B3.D1.80.D0.B0.D1.84.D0.BE.D0.B2). У Вас есть возможность оптимизировать решение отталкиваясь от информации является ли станция узловой, и относится ли она к одной и той-же линии. При этом критерием сложности я бы назвал количество обращений к базе данных.

Надеюсь здесь, в нескольких строках, мне удалось немного приблизить Вас к нужному варианту ответа по этой достаточно сложной задаче.

Comment: Спасибо, вот уже изучаю алгоритме Дейкстры

Comment: @Владислав не отбрасывайте сразу вариант построенный на алгоритме Флойда - Уоршелла. Если Ваши данные о растояниях ограничиваются десятками тысяч строк, поднятие их из БД произойдёт прктически мгновенно.

Comment: А в таблицу sTATION мне разве не надо еще название хотя бы? ну и саму ЖД?

Comment: К сожалению я не могу позволить себе дать настолько полный ответ, который можно будет взять и вставить в рабочий проект. Вы можете и должны расширить тот минимальный код который был предложен, для решения вашей задачи. Более того, я отбросил ту часть которая отвечает за название веток, за страны и прочие нюансы которые мне кажутся очевидными. Их вы можете добавить в отдельные таблицы, опираясь на понимание уровня нормализации который Вам нужен.

Comment: Так мой вопрос и есть в том, как правильно выстроить структуру. Как лучше создать таблицы и тд и тп. А не писать мне алгоритм поиска расстояния. У меня загвоздка в стуктуре

Comment: @Владислав опишите это в поставленном вопросе. М.б. кому-то будет интересно ответить и на этот вопрос.

Comment: На самом деле мне @Mike дал наводку даже и на алгоритм решения, даже я бы сказал это готовое решение и даже сослался на ваш ответ, что правильно описали, тут теперь правильно организовать саму бд и прикрутить алгоритм :) у меня есть таблица станций и даже есть 20000 строк расстояний готовых

Answer (score 2):

Возможно, я не совсем правильно понял задачу, но по идее, должна быть БД примерно такого вида:

[image: Схема данных БД]

В таблице "Дистанция" - расстояние между 2-мя соседними узлами.

В таблице "дороги" будет информации о движении по узлам. Так как от станции А до станции Б можно проложить путь несколькими способами, выходит, что дорога должна включать все узлы, даже те, где нет остановки. Там, где нет остановки, поле "код_станции" будет пустым. Примерно такая получится заполненная таблица с 2-мя дорогами:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Теперь, при выводе дороги можно получить все необходимые данные:

Порядок движения.
 1. Узлы (не для отображения)
 2. Станции (то есть остановки - для отображения)
 3. Расстояние (либо вычислять уже при выводе дороги в программу, для каждой строки выполнив запрос к табл. "дистанция", либо добавить в табл. "дороги" поле "код_дистанции" и заполнять его при добавлении данных в таблицу "дороги", если есть такая возможность. Также можно добавить триггеры, чтобы автоматизировать этот процесс).
 4. При необходимости дополнительным запросом получить страны (из таблицы "Узлы").

Возможно, подойдет такое решение. Наверное, что-то можно пересмотреть и улучшить, писал быстро. Например, в таблице "дороги" вроде как глупо указывать узел, если указан код_станции, дублирование получается. Можно убрать вообще поле код_узла, оставить только код_станции и добавить флаг "остановка".

UPD: обратил внимание, что все-таки неверно понял насчет узла. Если узел - это некий объект для группировки удаленных станций, тогда в схеме нужно "узлы" и "станции" поменять местами. Таблица "дистанция" будет хранить расстояния между станциями. А в таблице дороги убрать поле "узел" и добавить флаг "остановка".

Comment: Узел - это просто станция от которой есть более 2 направлений движения

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать всё связанными иерархическими таблицами: страна содержит список таблиц дорог, дорога - список таблиц узлов и т.п. Но это, на мой взгляд, неудобно.
Я бы свёл всё в одну таблицу (возможно, две, если будет нужна доп. информация), где будут и страны, и дороги, и узлы, и станции. Введите идентификатор, однозначно определяющий тип (пример: 1 - страна, 2 - дорога и т.п.), создайте референсы, указывающие на родителя (станция Толмачёвка имеет родителя за номером 81, а это - Измайловский узел и т.п.).
Расстояния тоже можно вводить по-разному. Логичнее, на мой взгляд, в километрах от начала узла. Так и рассчитывать расстояния между станциями будет проще.

Например, так:

```
CREATE TABLE `new_table` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL COMMENT 'уникальный ID',
  `ob_type` INT NOT NULL COMMENT 'тип объекта: 1 - страна, 2 -узел, 3 -дорога, 4 - станция',
  `parent_id1` INT NULL COMMENT 'ссылка на первого родителя - номер его ID',
  `parent_id2` INT NULL COMMENT 'ссылка на второго родителя - номер его ID',
  `parent_id3` INT NULL COMMENT 'ссылка на третьего родителя - номер его ID',
  `name` VARCHAR(90) NULL COMMENT 'Имя объекта',
  `distance` FLOAT NULL COMMENT 'расстояние от начала узла (только для станций)',
  `description` TEXT(2000) NULL COMMENT 'Описание',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)  COMMENT '',
  UNIQUE INDEX `id_UNIQUE` (`id` ASC)  COMMENT 'Комментарий');
```

Comment: я сейчас так выгрузил все в эксель, но возникла трудность, что у станции может быть несколько узлов

Comment: Несколько это сколько? Если не больше пяти и увеличения не предвидится, можно ввести несколько референсов. Теоретически, дорога может принадлежать двумя странам. Если больше пяти - строковое поле, где референсы указаны через разделитель.

Comment: Ну вот например Азербайджаская жд. 546808 Баладжары 192 0 ЯЛАМА (ЭКСП.) - БАЛАДЖАРЫ
546808 Баладжары 0 69 БАЛАДЖАРЫ - АЛЯТ
У станции Баладжары 2 узла

Comment: Я исправил ответ - таблица с тремя родительскими референсами.

Comment: Спасибо большое, есть теперь от чего оттолкнуться:) Осталось только все собрать

Comment: А зачем ссылки на 3х родителей ? Есть у нас запись id=100 у которой описаны все 3 родителя, скажем id 1,2,3. Что будет в этих родительских записях ? Структуру по дереву с 3 направлениями обходить дико не удобно, обычно достаточно одного родителя и главное, это исключает избыточность информации и исключает возможности нарушения ссылочной целостности

Comment: как показал автор вопроса, могут быть 2 родителя. Учитывая, что структуру, как правило, придётся обходить сверху вниз, вряд ли будут неудобства. Зато можно оперативно менять информацию о родителях, если она поменялась. Впрочем, для этого можно сделать и связанную таблицу.

Answer (score 0):

Надо отталкиваться от сущностей. Имеются:

1. Станции
2. Граф описывающий как эти станции соединены друг с другом (то есть станция по сути вершина графа)
3. Есть маршрут который идет по этому графу от узла к узлу (от вершины к вершине) - длина маршрута и есть искомая величина.

Итого получаются 3 таблицы, 1 и 3 самоочевидны. Есть сложность со 2-й таблицей - как описать граф. Ладно бы граф был в виде дерева, но в реальности все немного сложнее, поскольку это граф с кольцами, что-то типа такого:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я не совсем глубокий специалист в деле DDL/SQL, но я бы реализовал это через отношение *один-ко многим* - всегда есть 1 вершина, которая соединена с несколькими вершинами.

Как то так.